# Django Unit test : `freeze_time` not work well in some cases (Seems like a bug..?)

Tags: django, django-unittest, django-timezone, freezegun

This is my code for testing the role of `TIME_ZONE` and `USE_TZ:

```
from django.test.utils import override_settings

class TimeZoneTest(TestCase):

    @override_settings(TIME_ZONE='UTC', USE_TZ=True)
    @freeze_time("2018-01-04 13:30:55", tz_offset=9) # The reason that I add tz_offset=9 is to make local time samw with `Asia/Seoul`
    def test_freeze_time1(self):
        print("TIME_ZONE='UTC', USE_TZ=True")
        print(datetime.now())
        print(timezone.now())


    @override_settings(TIME_ZONE='UTC', USE_TZ=False)
    @freeze_time("2018-01-04 13:30:55", tz_offset=9)
    def test_freeze_time2(self):
        print("TIME_ZONE='UTC', USE_TZ=False")
        print(datetime.now())
        print(timezone.now())


    @override_settings(TIME_ZONE='Asia/Seoul', USE_TZ=True)
    @freeze_time("2018-01-04 13:30:55", tz_offset=9)
    def test_freeze_time3(self):
        print("TIME_ZONE='Asia/Seoul', USE_TZ=True")
        print(datetime.now())
        print(timezone.now())


    @override_settings(TIME_ZONE='Asia/Seoul', USE_TZ=False)
    @freeze_time("2018-01-04 13:30:55", tz_offset=9)
    def test_freeze_time4(self):
        print("TIME_ZONE='Asia/Seoul', USE_TZ=False")
        print(datetime.now())
        print(timezone.now())
```

**Result**

```
TIME_ZONE='UTC', USE_TZ=True
2018-01-04 22:30:55
2018-01-04 13:30:55+00:00

.TIME_ZONE='UTC', USE_TZ=False
2018-01-04 22:30:55
2018-01-04 22:30:55

.TIME_ZONE='Asia/Seoul', USE_TZ=True
2018-01-04 22:30:55
2018-01-04 13:30:55+00:00

.TIME_ZONE='Asia/Seoul', USE_TZ=False
2018-01-04 22:30:55
2018-01-04 22:30:55
```

The strange part is `test_freeze_time1()`, which tests under `TIME_ZONE='UTC', USE_TZ=True`, the reason that I think it strange is that `datetime.now()` doesn't print out `UTC` time, which is not True if I removed `@freeze_time("2018-01-04 13:30:55", tz_offset=9)` :

```
from django.test.utils import override_settings

class TimeZoneTest(TestCase):

    @override_settings(TIME_ZONE='UTC', USE_TZ=True)
    def test_freeze_time1(self):
        print("TIME_ZONE='UTC', USE_TZ=True")
        print(datetime.now())
        print(timezone.now())


    @override_settings(TIME_ZONE='UTC', USE_TZ=False)
    def test_freeze_time2(self):
        print("TIME_ZONE='UTC', USE_TZ=False")
        print(datetime.now())
        print(timezone.now())


    @override_settings(TIME_ZONE='Asia/Seoul', USE_TZ=True)
    def test_freeze_time3(self):
        print("TIME_ZONE='Asia/Seoul', USE_TZ=True")
        print(datetime.now())
        print(timezone.now())


    @override_settings(TIME_ZONE='Asia/Seoul', USE_TZ=False)
    def test_freeze_time4(self):
        print("TIME_ZONE='Asia/Seoul', USE_TZ=False")
        print(datetime.now())
        print(timezone.now())
```

**Result**

```
TIME_ZONE='UTC', USE_TZ=True
2018-02-13 09:10:49.715005
2018-02-13 09:10:49.715018+00:00

.TIME_ZONE='UTC', USE_TZ=False
2018-02-13 09:10:49.715970
2018-02-13 09:10:49.715980

.TIME_ZONE='Asia/Seoul', USE_TZ=True
2018-02-13 18:10:49.716758
2018-02-13 09:10:49.716769+00:00

.TIME_ZONE='Asia/Seoul', USE_TZ=False
2018-02-13 18:10:49.717475
2018-02-13 18:10:49.717486
```

As you can see here, both print out `UTC` time under `TIME_ZONE='UTC', USE_TZ=True` condition.

The other settings seem work well.

Or, Did I miss something?